# scrapy data extraction based on one class

Tags: python, scrapy

I am currently using scrapy to extract data if the given value is change I need to get output deep-thoughts if the given value is change_1 then I need to get the output deep-thoughts_1 if the given value is change_2 then I need to get the output deep-thoughts_2

```
 <div class="tags">
    <div class="giv">
    <h3 class="r">
    <a href="/tag/change/page/1/">change</a> </h3>
    <div class="s">deep-thoughts</div> </div>
   <div class="giv">
    <h3 class="r">
    <a href="/tag/change/page/2/">change_1</a> </h3>
    <div class="s">deep-thoughts_1</div> </div> 
   <div class="giv">
    <h3 class="r">
    <a href="/tag/change/page/2/">change_2</a> </h3>
    <div class="s">deep-thoughts_2</div> </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
data = "change"
value = response.xpath("//div[preceding-sibling::h3/a='{}']/text()".format(data)).extract_first()
```